# Using Angular2 with EpiServer setup

Tags: angular, development-environment, episerver

Has anyone yet tried using Angular2 together with EpiServer ?.
Any who have a tutorial for startup on such ?. Hope to hear from you.

Best regards

Comment: This post might prove useful: https://tedgustaf.com/blog/2017/episerver-on-page-edit-with-angular-react-and-other-js-frameworks/

Comment: Hi Ted, Thank you for your  reply, yes I have seen your article but I would like to see it implemented in a Angular2 (4) in Visual Studio 2017. It seems quite tricky. If one as example uses dotnet new Angular - the template creates a demo project for Angular and its in this project it would be nice to see a EpiServer hookup.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't specifically used Angular 2 with Episerver. My approach would be to separate the visitor UI from the editor-UI. One UI for the editor and pass JSON objects that you parse into angular 2 objects. This will give you a loosely coupled which makes it very easy for frontend developers to completely redo the UI later on. Complications with the edit view can arise when it doesn't reflect the actual UI of the visitor tho.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is too late to answer this, but maybe this is something useful.

https://github.com/angular/universal.

This project splits the ui and the server side. The benefit of this is that we can use Episerver for the server side rendering and angular for the ui. This project also has alot of the built in bundling and lazy loading that will help with your application performance.

Thanks

Paul

Comment: Hi Paul, Thank you for your message. Yes its a bit too late but non the less its worth knowing. Thank you